# Exceptions throwing for invalid argument inside a method

Tags: php, oop, exception, object, methods

I'm learning about Exception handling. I already know how to use them, however I don't know *when* to use them, since few tutorials tell you anything insightful about this. My code:

```
// 0-index part of the url
public function part($Part)
  {
  if (!is_numeric($Part))
    throw new Exception('The argument for $Url->part() should be numeric');

  $Part = (int) $Part;

  if ($Part < 0)
    throw new Exception('The argument for $Url->part() should be positive');

  if ($Part > count($this->parts))
    return false;

  return $this->parts[$Part];
  }
```

I feel that my code has too many exceptions. It's part of a code for retrieving the current url and some parts of them. e.g., `/this/is/a/test/` would be saved in `$this->parts` as `array('this', 'is', 'a', 'test')`.

**Am I using too many exceptions in that method, hindering the readability? Should I use only one exception if any of the problems arise, making it slightly more difficult to debug but easier to read the source code?**

This is the more generic exception named in the question:

```
// 0-index part of the url
public function part($Part)
  {
  if (!is_numeric($Part) || intval($Part) < 0 || intval($Part) > count($this->parts))
    throw new Exception('The argument for $Url->part() is not correct');

  return $this->parts[(int) $Part];
  }
```

Comment: Are you willing to process & raise out-of-bounds exception?

Comment: I typically don't use that many Exceptions, but not because of readability.  If you do this, you'll have to be handling (`try`/`catch`ing) your errors whenever you call `part()`.  I personally would return `false` on any errors, and when calling `part()`, check for a valid return before continuing.

Comment: The question really should be: Do you want to be able to differentiate between all those exceptions? Are they purely cosmetic (I would strip them down then) or do they have a purpose?

Comment: OP, to answer 'When should I use...' Exception handling question, you ask 'when is it important that I know why it failed?'. The catch all 'return false' or 'return null' is sloppy code, unless there is no need to know anything else. IE a function like isValid() should return true/false, but when something is fine tuned, like a value must be a digit, within a particular range, then its important to know what failed.

Comment: Validation of user input isn't an exception circumstance: exceptions should be used for the exceptional ("e.g. database has gone away") rather than routine form validation where invalid user inputs are a normal rather than exceptional circumstance

Comment: @Rottingham has a good point.  It really depends on your use-case and the level you need to know what is going on.

Comment: @Tobe, They have the purpose of letting the developer know when the method is receiving a parameter that is not allowed

Comment: Also: You allways raise the same exception without any means for your code to determine what actually happened. You code cant see a difference. If you want to differentiate between your various exceptions, you might either want to raise different Exception descendants or at leat set a code number for each case.

Comment: @Mark, it isn't user input what I want to validate, it's the programmer's input.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia Use Exception types for different purposes, but remember to be thorough. I use the Doctrine 2 system alot, and they have some of the crappiest exceptions. For instance, it throws an exception with absolutely no description of what failed or where, only that it failed. So exceptions can be overkill of not used properly. In your example you would probably use InvalidArgumentException('The argument for blah blah should be a number');

Comment: Even so, it's still not an Exception case like "Entire interweb has crashed"

Comment: @SamSullivan , for first comment, returning false gives too little information when trying to debug when something went wrong. Probably the `out-of-bonds` should return false, but if, for any reason, there's a bit of code calling `$Url->part(-1)`, this is not a normal flow problem, this is truly exceptional and definitely needs some investigation.

Comment: In this instance, if the index doesn't exist in the array, won't PHP throw an exception anyway? It all depends on what you are trying to achieve. Was this hypothetical?

Comment: @user2294382 No, exceptions aren't entirely native in PHP. It would just issue an `E_NOTICE` about the undefined index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your question is very close to *opinion-based* questions (thus it may be too hard to answer properly, without non-constructive discussion). However, there are some things that are useful to remember.

First, raising *just exception* may be improved - because there are standard [exceptions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php) in PHP. Throwing them will defenitely improve readability. For example, your code accept some argument that supposed to be numeric. If it isn't - then it's **invalid argument** - therefore, corresponding exception may be triggered. Next, your `parts` is an array - and you want to check if passed offset exists. If it isn't, then it's **out-of-bounds** exception. So your code may look like:

```
public function getPart($part)
{
   if(!is_numeric($part))
   {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid part number passed');
   }
   if(!array_key_exists($part, $this->parts))
   {
      throw new OutOfBoundsException('Offset '.$part.' not found in parts');
   }
   return $this->parts[$part];
}
```

-this seems to be reasonable for numeric offsets. However, if your structure contains more complex data, then you may want to raise **logic exception** (to point that there was error in logical structure of passed arguments or current structure).

In common case - it all *depends of situation and logic*. There's **no silver bullet** - it's about design and all solutions are relative and bound to certain situation.

Again, this is very *opinion-based*  (for example, I started from re-naming your method to `getPart()` - because for me method is an entity that should be named as action name, not just thing name). And, more - try to avoid mixing different type when returning something (like `false` in your sample). It causes unreliable behavior. Better to throw exception, but keep your function/method return type same.

Comment: I changed the title slightly to try to make it less `opinion-based`. +1 since this is a great answer that completely satisfies me. It makes the code even more readable than my original one (using semantic exceptions). However, it brings me another question that I'll investigate on my own, isn't this just using too many exception classes, increasing the *complexity* of the overall code?

Comment: You first need to decide what do you mean under _code complexity_

Comment: I mean many more lines of code needing to be written, tested and understood. (ideas taken from `Code Complete 2nd edition`, section 5.2).

Comment: Less lines of code don't mean that readability is better. There always be compromise. But if you know exactly what each line does, if you're sure about - how reliable and stable is your code - then, I think, it won't be too hard to find that compromise

Comment: No, I just meant that code is less complex if it has less lines of code in the overall product, while delivering a similar functionality. However, I agree about the compromise and I'm accepting your answer since it solves my original question, making the code more readable (and/or meaningful) while giving away valuable debugging info in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> @Mark, it isn't user input what I want to validate, it's the programmer's input.

Yes, that's overkill. If you want to sanity-check *programmer* input, user [`assert`](https://www.php.net/assert).

There is no reasonable way to handle an exception generated by *mistyped code*, or insane arguments, or incorrect use of a library, which is what you seem to be guarding against. There is no value to using exceptions as the mechanism to guard against such errors.

You raise an exception when something unexpected happens, and you can't deal with it gracefully. Exceptions pass control back up the stack, ideally to a level where that type of error *can* be handled, without the program failing. There is really no way at runtime to handle the kind of error you're guarding against. If somebody gives your library inputs that are so wrong that your library can only abort, the best thing we can do at that point is give the user as much debugging information as possible and exit; `assert` is purpose-built for this.

Note that I think even `assert` is usually over-kill. You're using a [duck-typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) language; who cares about the type of your arguments? So long as they respond to all the methods you're going to be invoking on them, your code should be happy to accept *any* kind of object. The only case I would consider using `assert` on my arguments is when I'm writing library code and I know I want to produce friendly error messages than PHP's.

Comment: I typed that too fast actually, it's not only the programmer's input what I want to validate, but a number of things, mainly programmers' input from other classes, database values and `$_SESSION` variables. However, I've never learned about nor used `assert()`, so I'll learn about it before choosing an answer.

Comment: `assert()` seems to only take the problem-handling to an external, custom-defined callback function, in a similar way as would be throwing a custom exception and not catching it.

On the other hand, in the documentation it specifies that `Assertions should not be used for normal runtime operations like input parameter checks. As a rule of thumb your code should always be able to work correctly if assertion checking is not activated.`, which is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Range checks(`>= 0`, `<= length`, etc), no, don't assert those. But you're checking the *type* of an object, something that should never change once the code is working. There's no set of user inputs that should change the *types* of your arguments. That's a case of something going wrong during the development of the code, and that's exactly what `assert` is meant to catch.